# Why is "for a tortuous three days" singular even though days is plural?

Tags: word-usage, word-order, singular-vs-plural

I was surprised to find out that you should write:

> > I waited for a torturous three days.

Instead of:

> > I waited for torturous three days.

Why is this? "Days" is plural ...

Comment: This is a good question. Just a side note, I think you probably mean *a [**torturous**](https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/chooseyourwords/tortuous-torturous/) three days*, unless the three days were particularly twisty.

Comment: @1006a There is also the meaning "excessively lengthy and complex"; I've certainly had days like that.

Comment: @JAB I've definitely had days like that, too! That's why I said *probably*, though I'd still prefer to use *tortuous* for the red tape or document analysis or medical appointments or what-have-you that make the day feel long, rather than the day itself.

Comment: Think of this construction as referring to a specific period, amount, or other "unit" of something, and then the quantity describes that single aggregation.  "**A** tortuous three days" means a single period that was three days long.  It is similar to how "**A** 12 inch ruler" is a single ruler that is 12 inches long, only the item isn't explicitly named, only implied.

Comment: 3 days is 1 thing, not 3 things. But good question :)

Comment: Related post on EL&U. [Indefinite articles used with plural nouns: It was AN amazing TWO DAYS](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252173/indefinite-articles-used-with-plural-nouns-it-was-an-amazing-two-days)

Comment: I once knew a girl that was shaped like a doughnut and was hard to get along with. She was born on May 1st and has been implicated in several violations of civil duties of care. She is a torturous tortious Taurus torus.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In phrases that follow this pattern:

a {modifier} {number} {plural noun relating to time}

{plural noun} is understood to be a *duration*.

> She spent a nervous thirty minutes waiting to be interviewed for the job.
>
> We spent a pleasant two weeks at the lake.
>
> He worked a grueling three years in the desert.

Comment: Not just "{plural noun relating to _time_}". E.g. "I walked a good three kilometers".

Comment: Yes, distances also follow the pattern. Any unit of measure.  *My captors injected me with a painful three ccs of snake venom.*  or *After a day in the hot sun, I drank a needed three cups of water.*

Comment: *The fever spiked to a dangerous 104 degrees F*.  *The skyscraper rose an impressive 200 storeys.*

Comment: The word order matters.  {number (other than 1)} {modifier} {plural noun} is plural.  For example, "I waited for three tortuous days" is grammatically correct.

Comment: @Jasper That's what I mentioned in my answer :D

Comment: Not just units of measure. Google Book Search finds, for example, "Moreover, this solitary genre produced **a mere eight works**, all of remarkably similar content"; "This theater probably seated **a good 200 people** and it was packed"; "Moreover, many Christians — [...] — include in the Old Testament **an additional six or seven books** as well as certain supplements to the books of Esther and Daniel [...]"; etc.

Comment: @ruakh: +1, though one might argue that "works", "people", and "books" are units-of-measure in those contexts.  Seating capacity is expressed in "people" or "persons", oeuvre in "works", and scriptural collections in "books".

Comment: In short: Because an amount is singular, even if the amount is not 1.

Answer (score 28):

In general, **dates & times**, lengths and weights<sup>[1](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/128127/why-is-for-a-tortuous-three-days-singular-even-though-days-is-plural#comment258294_128154)</sup>, amount of currency and Maths expressions **are not considered plural** even if they use plural forms of words. Like these

> Three days isn't a long time.
>   <s>Three days aren't a long time.</s>
>
> Ten miles is too long to walk.
>   Five kilograms isn't heavy for him to lift.
>   <s>Ten miles are too long to walk.</s>
>   <s>Five kilograms aren't heavy for him to lift.</s>
>
> Twenty pounds is too **little** to buy this.
>   <s>Twenty pounds are too **few** to buy this.</s>
>
> Two plus three is five.
>   <s>Two plus three are five.</s>

So, in your case, "tortuous three days" is considered as "a duration of **time**", so even if the word "day" is in its plural form, we do not consider the phrase as a plural form.
If you *really* want to treat it as plural, you can say

> I waited for three tortuous days.
>   <s>I waited for tortuously three days.</s>

In the upper way "days" will be treated as a regular noun, losing its meaning of "duration of time" **because an adjective is inserted in between** the number and "days".

Besides, as [*minnmass* mentioned in comments](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/128127/why-is-for-a-tortuous-three-days-singular-even-though-days-is-plural#comment258294_128154), this rule breaks down if the measure is a part of a whole. For example:

> Three days isn't a long time, unless two are rainy.

The first part of the sentence follows the rule, but the latter part doesn't, as "*two*" is part of the whole ("*three days*").

References: [This](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67553) and [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177112) on English.SE. A Google search query is also preferred.

---

<sub>1. Actually all physical measurements are never considered plural. For example, "10 Amperes is a large current" and "100 degrees Celsius is the boiling point of water"
and "101325 Pascals is the standard atmosphere pressure".</sub>

Comment: 10A is a large *current*; most major shops don't accept it as currency :)

Comment: There is another form of putting addition of numbers into words that treats the numbers as plural: "Two and two are four." But that seems very old-fashioned to me.

Comment: This rule breaks down if the measure is a part of a whole: "Three days isn't a long time, unless two are rainy".

Comment: @DavidK If you use "and" for conjunction, then it sounds better to me being plural. But if you use "plus, minus, multiplied by and so on", singular form is better.